# Аутентификация на основе http в PHP

Tags: php, http, аутентификация

Нашёл пример в интернете:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Текст, отправляемый в том случае,
    если пользователь нажал кнопку Cancel';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>Вы ввели пароль {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']}.</p>";
}
?>
```

но не могу понять. На основе чего происходит сравнение? Как сохранять логин и пароль для последующих проверок?
Подскажите, кому не лень

Comment: Это уже вам самому решать, как сравнивать и как сохранять, способов очень много

Comment: Это базовая авторизация. Логин-пароль приходят в запросе каждый раз. В кукисах это не хранится. Проверка логина-пароля обычно происходит по базе данных.